# pfSense: Have router connect, and route, to a PPTP server?

Tags: pptp, pfsense, multi-homed

i have a main office running a PPTP VPN server (Microsoft Remote Access Services). Is it possible for the pfSense router at a satellite location to automatically route traffic destined for the main location over a PPTP VPN link? (obviously via NAT, since the main office server wouldn't know how to route back to internal satellite machines)

```
Satellite        Main
192.168.x x      10.0.x.x
```

i can understand LAN traffic on Satellite destined for 10.0.0.11 would go to the **default gateway**.

At the **Satellite** location the default gateway is a **pfSense** router.

Conceivably, a static route could be created that sends traffic destined for `10.0.x.x` out the **vpn interface**. *e.g.*:

```
 Destination   Netmask        Gateway  
 ===========   ===========    ==========
 0.0.0.0       0.0.0.0        69.64.6.21   (WAN interface)
 10.0.0.0      255.255.0.0    10.0.1.221   (PPTP interface)
```

Traffic destined for `10.0.x.x` would have to be NAT'ed, just like traffic destined for the internet, since nobody would know how to route back to the IP of a client machine on the satellite LAN.

---

The pfSense docs mentions that the "**WAN PPTP**" feature cannot be used to create a separate, routable, WAN interface:

> [Can I use pfSense's WAN PPTP feature to connect to a remote PPTP VPN?](http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Can_I_use_pfSense's_WAN_PPTP_feature_to_connect_to_a_remote_PPTP_VPN%3F)
>
> The pfSense WAN PPTP feature is for
>   ISPs that require you to connect using
>   PPTP. This feature cannot be used as a
>   PPTP client to connect to a remote
>   PPTP server to allow pfSense to route
>   over the PPTP connection.

That doesn't mean that pfSense *cannot* do it - it just means that you can't use the **WAN PPTP** feature to do it. And concept is sound and possible, the question is: **can pfSense actually do it**.

**Edit:** Changing my not speak good