# pfSense 2.0 - Can PPP L2TP be used to be an L2TP tunnel?

Tags: pptp, ppp, pfsense

i noticed in pfSense 2.0 (RC3) that my PPPoE interface is now a PPPoE tunnel assigned to my WAN NIC (Network Interface Card):

[image]

where the `PPPOE0(xl0) - ianboyd@superuser.com` network port is defined on to **PPPs** tab:

[image]

i thought this was interesting, and i wonder if it was finally possible to [Have pfSense Connect and Route to a PPTP Server](https://superuser.com/questions/171545/pfsense-have-router-connect-and-route-to-a-pptp-server). It would be great if i could create a PPTP/L2TP tunnel (just like i have a PPPoE tunnel) that connects and knows to route traffic destined for the `10.0.0.0/16` out the PPP tunnel:

- Destination: **10.0.x.x**/16
- Interface: **L2TP(xl0)**

e.g. `route add 10.0.0.0 255.255.0.0 if OPT2`

So is it possible?

---

i tried creating the PPP tunnel:

[image]

My thought processes for each of the settings were:

- **Link Type**: PPTP

> My first reaction was to use `PPTP` vpn protocol, because for a decade that's all Windows supported. Then i remembered that `L2TP` has been around in Windows and Windows Server for a long time and maybe i can use that "*more standard*" one. But then i remembered that our work firewalls are all configured for `PPTP` (`1723` and `GRE`), so `PPTP` it is.

- **Link Interface(s)**: WAN

> i know i said `xl0` would be the interface that the tunnel is established on. But then i realized that the tunnel's traffic must be sent out an interface that can reach the internet. Strictly speaking my WAN network card is not connected to the internet - it only connects to the modem. The `WAN` interface (which is a PPPoE tunnel operating over xl0) is the actual *internet* interface.
>
> If pfSense tried to establish a L2TP on `xl0` the only device that would see the traffic is the modem. The traffic must go out the `PPPoE` tunnel, which means the **WAN** interface.

- **Description**: `VPN to Work`

> Pretty self-explanatory; any arbitrary text

- **Username**: ian
- **Password**: ••••••••••••••

> That is my username and password combination that work's VPN server will check.

- **Local IP (wan)**: 10.0.4.5 / 16

> Now is where my hope begins to fade. When i VPN to work from my Windows desktop i don't have to assign an IP address; the server **automatically** gives me one. Much the same way that the PPPoE tunnel doesn't need an IP. Maybe i can just leave it blank?:

- **Local IP (wan)**:

> It took it, so i'll leave it blank instead

- **Gateway (wan)**: 216.8.132.226

> This must be the address of the vpn server at work (i.e. IP address *of* work).

Now that i have the tunnel created, i can return to **Interfaces** and create a new interface out of this tunnel:

[image]

Except that when i save the changes it new OPT1 interface reverts to `xl0` rather than my new PPP tunnel.

So i'm stuck

Comment: I do not know, but +1 for a very well-written question.

Comment: Took me 2 hours to do it :(

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a bug in pfSense. You use DNS name vpn.superuser.com as a remote gateway address, but in fact code does not resolve DNS, it expects only IP address.

[Proof link to source code](https://github.com/pfsense/pfsense/blob/master/etc/inc/interfaces.inc#L1468)

Try to use IP address instead of DNS name, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In the title the question is about L2TP, but due to detailed description I can see that PPTP is used in fact.

Here is what Official [pfSense FAQ sais](http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Can_I_use_pfSense%27s_WAN_PPTP_feature_to_connect_to_a_remote_PPTP_VPN?) about that:

> Q: Can I use pfSense's WAN PPTP feature to connect to a remote PPTP
>   VPN?
>
> A: The pfSense WAN PPTP feature is for ISPs that require you to
>   connect using PPTP. This feature cannot be used as a PPTP client to
>   connect to a remote PPTP server to allow pfSense to route over the
>   PPTP connection.